# How to work in two different docker accounts simultaneously with docker desktop in windows?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, multi-user

I have two docker accounts one contains company's images & containers another is for my personal projects. So, need to be secure and not clumsy in both docker account's images or containers..

I have also tried by creating multiple users in my system and logged_in in different users.. but there faced an Error:"docker is already running"

how to do this?
Please guide me a best way.. since I am a noob in docker..